# How do I split a Spark rdd Array[(String, Array[String])] to a single RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to split the following RDD into a single `RDD(id,(all name same type))`.

```
>val test = rddByKey.map{case(k,v)=> (k,v.collect())}  

test: Array[(String, Array[String])] =   
  Array(
    (45000,Array(Amit, Pavan, Ratan)),
    (10000,Array(Kumar, Venkat, Sheela)), 
    (50000,Array(Tejas, Dinesh, Lokesh, Bhupesh))
  )
```

I want to print it like this:

```
(45000,(Amit, Pavan, Ratan))
(10000,(Kumar, Venkat, Sheela))
```

This is what I have tried

```
val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/data.csv") 
val rdd = data.map(r=>(r.split(",")(0),r.split(",")(1))) 
val groupByKey = rdd.groupByKey().collect() 
val rddByKey = groupByKey.map{case(k,v) => k->sc.makeRDD(v.toSeq)} 
val test = rddByKey.map{case(k,v)=> (k,v.collect())}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here. You want have `rddByKey` and you want to split it how exactly? Can you add someclearer input/expected output examples?

Comment: How can `rdd.map` possibly become an `array`?

Comment: val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/data.csv")
val rdd = data.map(r=>(r.split(",")(0),r.split(",")(1))) 
val groupByKey = rdd.groupByKey().collect()     
val rddByKey = groupByKey.map{case(k,v) => k->sc.makeRDD(v.toSeq)} 
val test = rddByKey.map{case(k,v)=> (k,v.collect())}  <------Wan to collect it as (k,(Values of Array for same key))

Comment: why would you want to print it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to go through such complexity of using `collect`. you can simply do

```
val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/data.csv")
val rdd = data.map(r=>{
  val x = r.split(",")
  (x(0),x(1))
})
val groupByKey = rdd.groupByKey().map{case (x, y) => (x :: y.toList)}
```

`groupByKey` is

```
List(45000, Amit, Pavan, Ratan)
List(10000, Kumar, Venkat, Sheela)
List(50000, Tejas, Dinesh, Lokesh, Bhupesh)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Can you please say how do I fetch index(0) value of flatMap .   Please find below are my code , Not able to get value of content1(0) .                              code:                                                                                                  val file1 = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/file1.txt")

val content1 = file1.flatMap(line=>line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1))
val file1Word = sc.makeRDD(Array(content1(0)._1+content1(0)._2))

Comment: For now I will just answer your above comment query but from next time please ask a different question for new contexts. It seems that you are trying to do work count , if thats so then this code should work for you :: `val file1 = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/file1.txt")
    val content1 = file1.flatMap(line=>line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1))
    val file1Word = content1.reduceByKey(_ + _)`  If the above answer helped you then please consider accepting it. :)

Comment: for example : -                                                                                   
              o/p val content1 :-  (are,2) (is,1)(the,1)                                           
              Now I want to get {(is,1)} ..                                                               
please suggest how can I get it .

Comment: I did . please share you ans..                                                                                 the value of flatMap :-  content1 :- (are,2) (is,1)(the,1)                        
 Now I want to get {(is,1)} .. how it's possible .

Comment: You should use filter `val file1 = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/file1.txt") 
    val content1 = file1.flatMap(line=>line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    content1.filter(_._1 == "is")` and you should get (is, 1).